# Is it possible for git to keep unchanged files untouched when switching branches?

Tags: makefile, git-checkout

I have a project which uses custom defined files to generate source files and then compiles them (which takes a lot of time). Only the custom defined files are tracked by git. Every time I switch my branch git touches all the files which triggers the generation of all source files and hence the compilation. I want to save time by making git touch only those files that are different between the two local branches and hence reduce my make time.

Please enlighten on the possibilities of achieving such a feat.

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Comment: @RonySamuel Seems pretty clear... the OP wants to avoid touching files whose content doesn't differ between the branches, since touched files trigger a rebuild.

Comment: I vaguely recall that this is something that was fixed at some point... what version of Git are you using?

Comment: @Sneftel I am using v1.7.9.5. I doubt it is a bug which needs to be fixed.

Comment: Wow, retro. ;-) Yeah, poking around I think this was fixed in 2.2.2 or so. (Not a bug per se, but definitely a misfeature.)

Comment: can you refer to the commit that introduces this feature? or the mailing thread that discusses this issue? maybe I can encourage my team to upgrade the version then :)